# how to reload context of the application using JavaMelody?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7, probe, server-monitoring, java-melody

I have been using Probe to monitor tomcat server and web application.From Probe I can reload the context from the UI,clicking on refresh icon.

But I am not getting from where to reload context in JavaMelody?

I have added 2 jar files in lib folder of my application javamelody-1.39.0.jar and jrobin-1.5.9.jar and added below snippet in web.xml file

```
        <filter>
                <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
                <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
        <listener>
                <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
```

And monitoring the application using the url `http://localhost:8080/appName/monitoring`

From the resultant UI ,how to reload the context of that particular application?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to reload the context of the webapp using the javamelody UI. There is no action for that.